# Particular solution to nonhomogenous differential equation $y''-6y'+9y=9t+3$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I continue my quest of finishing a problem where I
[previously calculated the unique solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2868985/unique-solution-to-homogeneous-second-order-differential-equation)
to a second order homogeneous differential equation and got the right answer in the end.

Now though, I have to *Determine which of the following function expressions is a (particular) solution of the non-homogeneous differential equation*
$$y''-6y'+9y=9t+3 \tag{1}\label{original}$$
with the following possible answers:
$$ \begin{array}{l|l}
    a) t+1               & d)e^{3t}+t+1     \\ 
    b) t^2+\frac{t}{2}-1 & e)-2te^{3t}+t+1  \\ 
    c) 9t+\frac{17}{3}   & f)e^{3t}-te^{3t} \\
    \end{array} $$

---

I understand that the general solution, $y$, equals $y_h+y_p$ where $y_h$ is the general solution to the homogeneous equation $\bigl(y_h(t)=2e^{3t}+te^{3t} \bigr)$ and $y_p$ is any particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation. And if I follow the theory of my text book and Sal Khan from *Khan Academy* then I have to make a shrewd guess of what $y_p$ might be. So, since the differential equation equals a polynomial my guess of $y_p$ will be the polynomial:

$y_p=At+B \tag{2}\label{y_p}$ which gives us, 
$y_p'=A$ and 
$y_p''=0$

I then substitute these back into the original equation (\ref{original}) and get:
$$1\cdot (0) -6 \cdot (A) + 9\cdot(At+B)=9t+3\Rightarrow 9At-6A+9B=9t+3$$

We know that whatever the t-coefficients add up to be on the left-hand side they should be equal to the right-hand side, same goes for the constants. Let's calculate and solve for A and B:

$9A=9 \Rightarrow A=1$

$-6 \cdot 1 + 9B=3 \Rightarrow 9B = 3 + 6 \Rightarrow B=1$

We insert A and B into (\ref{y_p})

$y_p=t+1$

$y=y_h+y_p=\bigl(2e^{3t}+te^{3t}\bigr)+(t+1) \tag{3}\label{y}$

Final question: How would $y$ look when added together and why does the results-list say the correct answers are $a), d)$ and $e)$?

Thanks in advance =)

**Edit:**
I think that the professor wants the particular solution as well as the solution of the non-homogeneous D.E. because of the way he puts parentheses around the word *particular*, and that's why $a)$ is correct, but then I just need to understand how $d)$ and $e)$ are results as well.

Comment: I have got $$y_p=t+1$$ check it.

Comment: Yes that's what I got as well, and results-list says that it is correct but d) and e) are correct as well which I don''t quite understand..

Comment: Let $y=(C_1e^{3t}+C_2te^{3t})$ is general solution and $y=t$ is particulat, then $y_1=2e^{3t}+5te^{3t}+t$ is a solution. So if we separate $y_1$ and write $y_1=e^{3t}+5te^{3t}+(t+e^{3t})$, then $(t+e^{3t})$ is a particular solution as well???

Comment: How did you get that $y_h=2e^{3t} + t e^{3t}$ without any initial data?

Comment: While it is true that $y_p = t+1$ is a Particular Solution (in the sense that the phrase presumably has a mathematical definition), its also true that the answers $a,d,e$ are particular solutions (i.e., they are examples of solutions)

Comment: @CalvinKhor, It was calculated in the linked post =)

Comment: That question is only linked to this by the fact that the ODE involved is the same.

Comment: @user108128, It irritates me that I can't see where you get the 5 and +t from, in $y_1$, can you describe it in more detail?

 well.. I did calculate it before and then referenced  it in this text with the hyperlink because it is connected to this problem

Comment: That was an example!

Comment: @JayFreddy What he is saying is precisely that for the example that he talked about (i.e. not your ODE specifically) the 5 and 2 are completely arbitrary.

Comment: Arh, yes i couldn't see it before but it makes sence thx guys =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=C_1e^{3t}+C_2te^{3t}$ is the general solution of the equation and $y=t+1$ is the particular solution, then 
$$y_0=C_1e^{3t}+C_2te^{3t}+t+1$$
is a particular solution for every **specific** numbers $C_1$ and $C_2$. For instance 
$$y_0=6e^{3t}+5te^{3t}+(t+1)=5e^{3t}+5te^{3t}+(t+1+e^{3t})$$
is a particular solution as well.

Comment: oh okay, I thought that I had to use the $y(t) = 2e^{3t} + te^{3t}$ and not $y(t)=c_1 e^{3t}+c_2 te^{3t}$, it makes sence now, thx =)

Comment: Good luck......

Answer (score 0):

All the solution are in the form

$$y=y_h+y_p=\bigl(c_1e^{3t}+c_2te^{3t}\bigr)+(t+1)$$

and the only compatible answers are $a$,$d$ and $e$.